# Copy paste from multiple sheet to one sheet ( only required multiple columns and set auto filter on consolidated sheet and seprate)

Tags: excel, vba

I have three sheets (Sheet1,sheet2 and sheet5)Need to copy from sheet1 column "A","B","E"paste to "Sheet5 "c","G","H" and copy from sheet2 column "J","K", "N" paste to " Sheet5 "c","G","H" (should not overwrite) and Sheet5 i have first three rows are my headers under this it should paste Sheet5 column "G" which has data from sheet1 and sheet2:Need to seperate using autofilter for the specific text "JOhn","Alex","france" only.Separate sheet name should be "JOhn","Alex","france".Need your help on the code:I have tried on below code which is not working for my requirement and am not able to edit because of more conditions( I got from google ) Sub copypaste() Dim lastrow As Integer, erow As Integer, sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") lastrow = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row For i = 2 To lastrow erow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row sheet2.Cells(erow, 2) = sheet1.Cells(i, 3) sheet2.Cells(erow, 3) = sheet1.Cells(i, 6) sheet2.Cells(erow, 4) = sheet1.Cells(i, 9) Next i End Sub

Comment: Sub copypaste()
Dim lastrow As Integer, erow As Integer, sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet

Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastrow = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    erow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 2) = sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 3) = sheet1.Cells(i, 6)
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 4) = sheet1.Cells(i, 9)
Next i

'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns().AutoFit
'sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Activate
End Sub

Comment: Sub copypaste1()
Dim lastrow As Integer, erow As Integer, sheet5 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet

Set sheet5 = Worksheets("sheet5")
Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastrow = sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    erow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 2) = sheet5.Cells(i, 3)
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 3) = sheet5.Cells(i, 6)
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 4) = sheet5.Cells(i, 9)
Next i

'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns().AutoFit
'sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Activate
End Sub

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code (as text).

Comment: Am using above codes which is not helping me

Comment: Separate sheet name should be "JOhn","Alex","france"

Comment: @Basavarajk.s. Code in comments is usless because it is not readable. Line breaks matter in VBA code but in comments you cannot see them. Please [edit] your original question and add the code there. Format it correctly as codeblock using the buttons in the toolbar of the editor or ctrl + K.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyDataWithoutHeaders()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim shLast As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    'Fill in the start row
    StartRow = 2

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh and sh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)
            shLast = LastRow(sh)

            'If sh is not empty and if the last row >= StartRow copy the CopyRng
            If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then

                'Set the range that you want to copy
                Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))

                'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
                If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                End If

                'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
                'values or want to copy everything look below example 1 on this page
                CopyRng.Copy
                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With

            End If

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

See the link below for more details.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win002.htm